# Would a Nuclear bomb have any effect on the sun that could damage the earth?

Tags: nuclear-physics, climate-science

I was asked this recently and wasn't sure. The power of the sun is much more powerful than that of a Nuclear explosion but the question was what is the worst that could happen, we are assuming a situation where the nuclear bomb wasn't itself immediately destroyed by proximity of the sun for whatever reason.

So, for example, if it was near the surface, could that cause a massive sun spot or similar which could disrupt electronics

b.t.w. my background isn't a physics one :-)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tsar bomb released an energy of $240 \mathrm{PJ}$ .

The sun releases an energy of $10^{26} \mathrm{J}$ per second.

That means there is a difference of $9$ orders of magnitude (supposing that the bomb released all it energy in a second), so the effect is negigible.

It's like comparing the output of a coal power plant and a microwave oven.

Comment: Note: not "10⁹ orders of magnitude" — it is "9 [orders of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)".

Comment: Could the neutrons released from the bomb, result in an unstable chain reaction?  If no, then your answer is all that needs to be said.

Comment: @RijulGupta Such an explosion would release [maybe a few kilograms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113758/44126) of free neutrons, so no. And anyway, "chain reactions" are a feature of fission (where each fission releases more catalyzing neutrons); fusion reactions are essentially governed by temperature and pressure.